# Bind gif image to cursor?

Tags: python, events, mouse, bind

Is thre a way to bind and image to the cursor?

I have an event, for the moment it doen'st do much, just this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def evento(event):
    print("explosion"), event.x, event.y

f = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
f.bind("<Enter>", evento)
f.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm mostly seen how the events works but I need to bind and image(circle) and then when it enters change it for gif ot at least that's why I'm thinking of, don't know if I can program an animation or not in tkinter

Comment: you want to change the default appearance of the cursor on enter yes?

Answer (score 0):

From [python docs](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/563401-tkinter-strange-behavior-using-place-changing-cursors): try this example

```
def buildFrame(self):
self.f = Frame(self.master, height=32, width=32, relief=RIDGE,
borderwidth=2)
self.f.place(relx=.5,rely=.5)
#self.f.bind( '<Enter>', self.enterFrame )
#self.f.bind( '<Leave>', self.leaveFrame )
self.f.configure(cursor = 'circle')
```